# jQuery to force all favicon.ico requests to the correct location?

Tags: jquery, favicon

I do not have server-side access.

I'm trying to present a custom favicon from a hosted wiki service that provides scripting and CSS access but presents its own favicon to all its users.

Is it possible to do something [like this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-favicon-requests-to-correct-location/) but with jQuery? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is Javascript, which runs client-side once a page has been returned.

The request for the favicon is a pure HTTP request from browser to server, no page is loaded. You can only redirect requests like that using server-side techniques (such as the one you linked to).

There are a million ways you can do it server-side (.htaccess files, php redirects, etc.) but jQuery simply is not an option.

Comment: 100% true and upvoted. Worth mentioning that you can use `<link>` to tell the browser where to make the HTTP request from.

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable way is to put /favicon.ico at the root of your site. But to point to another image you can use code like this, as featured at the [Wikipedia favicon page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/somepath/image.ico" />
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/somepath/image.ico" />
```

Adjust the path and `type` value to match the image type.

No jQuery, though I suppose you could write JavaScript to inject these tags into the `<head>` so browsers would see them, but it seems easier just to add the html `<link>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

No. The search engine spiders mentioned as issues in that post will not load and execute your JavaScript code.